# How do I clone postgres database schemas in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to postgres.

But I have a project that's using it. It has the tables, constraints, triggers and functions. Let's call this one DB1 for simplicity sake.

Now I want to create a new project based on the existing one. When it comes to the database, I need to create exactly the same database as the existing one but with empty data. Just like a new fresh start of the project. So any incremental number value starts from 0. Let's call the new database DB2.

Both projects are using the same Google Cloud PostgreSQL instance. So I went to GC console and created DB2 in the same instance.

Then I read through the documentations here and here, but it is for exporting and importing the whole database (including the data). In my case, I want a new database, empty data, but all tables, constraints, triggers, functions, all exist. As I understand it correctly, what I need to copy are the schemas from DB1 to DB2 (Please correct me if I'm wrong though).